# Question regarding slice assignment, deep copy and shallow copy in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-copy

When I tried to solve the classic N-queen problem in Leetcode, I was confused about the use of slice assignment, deep copy, and shallow copy. In the following code, I define three identical classes with only the exception in the first block of respective **backtrack** functions.

In class **Solution1**, I use slice assignment, `self.res.append([x[:] for x in board])`, to collect answers. In class **Solution2**, I use shallow copy, `self.res.append(copy.copy(board))`, which apparently ends up with a wrong answer. In class **Solution3**, I use deep copy, `self.res.append(copy.deepcopy(board))`, which returns the correct answer as expected.

To my understanding, a `slice assignment` implements a `shallow copy` as well. If this is the case, why a slice assignment in Solution1 can return a correct answer? Can anyone recommend a learning mateiral/website that I can refer to for better understanding their difference?

```
class Solution1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.res = []
    
    def solveNQueens(self, n: int) -> List[List[str]]:
        board = [['.' for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)] 
        self.backtrack(board, 0)
        return self.res

    def backtrack(self, board, row):
        
        if row == len(board):
            self.res.append([x[:] for x in board]) 
            return 
        
        for col in range(len(board)):
            
            if not self.isValid(board, row, col): 
                continue 

            board[row][col] = 'Q'
            self.backtrack(board, row + 1)
            board[row][col] = '.'

    def isValid(self, board: List[List[str]], row: int, col: int) -> bool:
        n = len(board)
        for i in range(row): 
            if board[i][col] == 'Q': 
                return False
        for i in range(1, row + 1):
            if col + i < n and board[row - i][col + i] == 'Q': 
                return False
            if col - i >= 0 and board[row - i][col - i] == 'Q': 
                return False
        return True       

class Solution2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.res = []
    
    def solveNQueens(self, n: int) -> List[List[str]]:
        board = [['.' for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)] 
        self.backtrack(board, 0)
        return self.res

    def backtrack(self, board, row):
        
        if row == len(board):
            self.res.append(copy.copy(board)) 
            return 
        
        for col in range(len(board)):
            
            if not self.isValid(board, row, col): 
                continue 

            board[row][col] = 'Q'
            self.backtrack(board, row + 1)
            board[row][col] = '.'

    def isValid(self, board: List[List[str]], row: int, col: int) -> bool:
        n = len(board)
        for i in range(row): 
            if board[i][col] == 'Q': 
                return False
        for i in range(1, row + 1):
            if col + i < n and board[row - i][col + i] == 'Q': 
                return False
            if col - i >= 0 and board[row - i][col - i] == 'Q': 
                return False
        return True   

class Solution3:
    def __init__(self):
        self.res = []
    
    def solveNQueens(self, n: int) -> List[List[str]]:
        board = [['.' for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)] 
        self.backtrack(board, 0)
        return self.res

    def backtrack(self, board, row):
        
        if row == len(board):
            self.res.append(copy.deepcopy(board)) 
            return 
        
        for col in range(len(board)):
            
            if not self.isValid(board, row, col): 
                continue 

            board[row][col] = 'Q'
            self.backtrack(board, row + 1)
            board[row][col] = '.'

    def isValid(self, board: List[List[str]], row: int, col: int) -> bool:
        n = len(board)
        for i in range(row): 
            if board[i][col] == 'Q': 
                return False
        for i in range(1, row + 1):
            if col + i < n and board[row - i][col + i] == 'Q': 
                return False
            if col - i >= 0 and board[row - i][col - i] == 'Q': 
                return False
        return True
```

Comment: Solution 1 is a comprehension which returns a new list, same with `deepcopy`... With regular `copy` you are just returning more or less a pointer to the same object. This is described in the docs for each... For example the comprehension: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: That's not slice assignment. Slice assignment is when you have a slice on the left side of `=`, e.g. `l1[:] = l2`

Comment: What you have in solution 1 is two levels of shallow copying. The list comprehension does a shallow copy of the outer list, and the slices make a shallow copy of the nested lists. If your original data is only 2 levels deep, this is the same as a deep copy.

Comment: `self.res.append([x[:] for x in board])` is *not* slice assignment. In any case, for a list of lists of strings, it is equivalent to a`deepcopy`, but more efficient